# Using encrypted password for database connection in spring boot web application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jasypt

This might be already answered or asked by some one else already, but I am not able to find one which satisfies my use case.
I am making a database connection in my spring boot web application(Note: My application is packaged as "WAR" and it does not contain the embedded tomcat) by specifying the following properties in my application.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:teradata://localhost/database=test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

By using above properties I am able to make the database connection successfully, now I want to place a encrypted password instead of a simple password. and I am using below command to encrypt the password using below command

```
java -cp jasypt-1.9.2.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="mypassword" password=SimplePassword algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
```

I am getting the encrypted one as "IlwjvmfqoPXVbyue17zN6Hx8mlJnGIuu" and I am placing it as following in properties file

```
spring.datasource.password=ENC(IlwjvmfqoPXVbyue17zN6Hx8mlJnGIuu)
```

But spring unable to identify it as encrypted(Since, i am not specifying any where that it is a encrypted value and it needs to be decrypted before using it.

I am fairly new to the spring boot development, if anyone know how to do this, please guide me, that would be really helpful. I have followed this link but unable to get it working "https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt"

From the response by @夢のの夢, I have added the dependency and made the version as 2.1.0 and the property "jasypt.encryptor.password=SimplePassword" I have added it to the file "application.properties" and I am able to build the application perfectly and it is making the connection pool successfully, but when I run it on the tomcat server from my eclipse I am getting the following error

```
2019-01-23 09:22:29.855 ERROR 16636 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.configuration.EncryptablePropertyResolverConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: myProject
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@3fee733d
]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:195) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanTypeForNonAliasDefinition(BeanTypeRegistry.java:159) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.addBeanType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:152) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:140) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.updateTypesIfNecessary(BeanTypeRegistry.java:135) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry.getNamesForType(BeanTypeRegistry.java:97) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:298) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:289) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:278) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:189) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/StringEncryptor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    ... 73 common frames omitted

2019-01-23 09:22:29.866  WARN 16636 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.configuration.EncryptablePropertyResolverConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: myProject
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@3fee733d
]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:583) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:568) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:626) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:662) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:507) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:477) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:590) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1204) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:905) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:891) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:877) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:826) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5120) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1382) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1372) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:907) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:933) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:637) [catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.14]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jasypt/encryption/StringEncryptor
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1173) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.14]
    ... 55 common frames omitted

2019-01-23 09:22:29.872 ERROR 16636 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start
```

Is there any other configuration I am doing wrong here?, why my application is able to build fine with all the tests completing successfully but unable to run on server?, if anyone seen the above error please let me know why it is causing that error.
Thank you all.

Comment: you can even hide the password by, passing as the environment variables only.
-Dspring.datasource.password=TheSimplePassword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since, i am not specifying any where that it is a encrypted value and it needs to be decrypted before using it

You don't need to. If you include the below dependency, Spring Boot auto configures default jasypt for you. You just need to ensure you add the secret key to your VM, such as `Djasypt.encryptor.password=SimplePassword`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>{your_version_goes_here}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. I have added the dependency and added the following property "jasypt.encryptor.password=SimplePassword" in my application.properties file and able to build the project perfectly but when I am right clicking-> run on server is giving me an error

Comment: ```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration.mbeanExporter
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.configuration.EncryptablePropertyResolverConfiguration] from ClassLoader [ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context:
```
If you know this error, please let me know what I am doing wrong here or do I need to mention any where for tomcat to know that I am using jasypt.

Comment: Hmm I am seeing `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jasypt.encryption.StringEncryptor`. Did you import your dependency?

Comment: Yes I have included the dependency and I can see the jar files related to jasypt in the lib folder of the generated war file. And if that is really causing the problem it should give the same problem when I am building it as well.

Comment: Okay this is outside of scope of this question.. I just tested on my local (Using IntelliJ) and it works fine. It still looks to me that your Spring Boot app is not able to find jasypt-1.9.2.jar in its classpath. Try to do a clean (clearing Maven's cache) and rebuild.

Comment: Yes, this is outside of scope of this question. I have removed it from my tomcat and rebuild and re-deployed, now it is working, thank you very much for your patients and testing it on your end as well.